# How to delete mesaage from xammp server in ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-api, ejabberd-saas

I am new in  ejabberd,

In our application need to delete chat messages functinality. so that one question in our mind

Can ejabberd delete message from xammp server using restApi..or other way...?

what is best way for same.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a "xampp" server is, and don't know what kind of stored messages do you want to delete. The ones stored temporarily by mod_offline? Or the ones stored persistently by mod_mam?

In both cases, those modules do not provide any command to delete a specific message, filtered by some message content.

If you look at the result of "ejabberd help", the command remove_mam_for_user allows to remove all the mam messages stored for an account.

Comment: Thanks,Badlop
I want to delete message from p2p chat message like whatsapp

Ex:

A: Hello B How'r u.
B: Fine and U...?
A: fine


If user A is delete his message from chat then message remove from both user chat screen.
and this message is never comeback from xmpp server.


Note:-

1) If I delete message from ejarbberd mysql database then it's possible to delete from xampp server..?

Comment: MAM specification does not allow deleting messages from archive.